# Bootstrap 4 modal not working when button clicked from a dropdown

Tags: html, css, django, bootstrap-4

I know this question was asked many times but I think I've tried everything... I have a bootstrap dropdown and the dropdown item should open a modal. But it is not showing. Nothing happens when the button is clicked.. **The modal works as expected when I click it with a normal button instead of a dropdown button.** FYI, the html below is reiterated in a for loop (for every comment in a post). Not sure if that matters? maybe the dropdown needs a unique id?

```
<div class="dropdown" style="float:right;">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
    •••
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-menu">
        <button type="button" class="dropdown-item delete-btn{{ comment.id }}" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#commentdeleteModal-{{ comment.id }}">
    Delete
    </button>
    </div>
</div>


<div class="modal" id="commentdeleteModal-{{ comment.id }}" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title">Delete</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Are you sure you want to delete the comment? <br>
        This can’t be undone.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <form action="{% url 'comment-delete' comment.id %}" method="POST" class="comdelete-form" id="{{ comment.id }}">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <div class="form-group">
                <button class="btn btn-danger" type="submit">Delete</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary closebtn" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </form> 
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

seems like an easy problem.. my head hurts.. thx

Comment: try 
        <button type="button" class="dropdown-item" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#commentdeleteModal-{{ comment.id }}">

Comment: sigh.. i did try that.. didn't work for me. it's weird cause the modal works when I click it with a normal button instead of a dropdown button.

Comment: do you have a javascript event on delete-btn{{ comment.id }}

Comment: yes deletes an object

Comment: i just tried to take out ".delete-btn{{ comment.id }" and tried it but same thing. nothing happens

Comment: suppress the javascript event on that element, that might triggers the problem

Comment: send the javascript code link to the event of delete-btn{{ comment.id }}

Answer (score 0):

I'd rather change instead of a `<button>` with `<a>`. Let me be more clear:

```
<div class="dropdown" style="float:right;">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
•••
</button>
<div class="dropdown-menu">
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-item delete-btn{{ comment.id }}" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#commentdeleteModal-{{ comment.id }}">
Delete
</a>
</div>
```

Let me know if that did the trick

Comment: I tried that as well and it didn't work.. it just scrolls to top of the page. I even tried href="#!" nothing happens

Comment: Did you try to remove the # from the href?

Comment: removing the # redirects me to the home page

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57343900/bootstrap-4-modal-not-showing-when-triggered-from-inside-a-dropdown
I may have found something useful for you. Actually, try adding a `<div class="container">` as the guy who replied the question did.

Comment: i tried that as well.. I really appreciate your help on this